# Are recipient type differences sufficient to make a question non-duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[What are the tax etc. implications of giving a friend's company an interest free loan?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54933/giving-a-friend-an-interest-free-loan) has been marked as a duplicate of question [How do you declare an interest free loan?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30504/how-do-you-declare-an-interest-free-loan), however, the former involves lending money for [to] a business. Since the entity to whom the loan is made is significantly different there are answers to one that would not apply to the other; my own answer would refer to taking equity in the company and the tax and personal finance differences resulting from taking equity in the firm over lending at a non commercial rate. That answer also covers both effects on the firm's and the lender's finances. Since there is a different legal status of the recipient in each case and the posters care about the recipient as an entity differently can we not say that these are not duplicates?

Comment: note: blame any stylistic problems with this question on my liquid lunch

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, if it had a better title that actually reflected the question asked I don't think it would have been marked a duplicate. The current title isn't really a question at all (the question mark doesn't make it one).

Comment: *facetiously* if the title is supposed to be the question what is the rest of the question for?

more seriously rather than marking it as a duplicate, therefore, shouldn't the mods have edited the title?

Comment: I edited the title and the question a little, hopefully that will go some way to redeeming a question that I think might be rather good.

Comment: The title should provide a succinct summary of the question with the details in the body. It should not be a word for word copy of the question. This helps others, who may have the same question, find it easily. As to your other question, two people voted it duplicate and I was neither of them. Who knows if they agree that it could be saved by re-phrasing it as a question?

Comment: Sorry, liquid lunch strikes, I didn't mean to be argumentative I only meant to suggest that poorly titled questions should have the title changed rather than being declared duplicates if they are reachable. I don't pretend to know what the others think either I just wanted guidance on whether the differences, however well hidden, may be enough to make it a redeemable question in its own right

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the problems of the original question, this will occur from time to time where a question is asked that's more-or-less identical to another.

The correct process that should follow is that it should be marked as a duplicate; and then, if the original poster agrees, left alone.  If the original poster does not feel the other post answers his/her question, they should either edit the question to more specifically address that issue, or ask a new question if needed (if it's too big of a change).

For example, take the following "original" question:

> If I loan some money without interest (but expecting payment) to someone, does it constitute a gift?

And then the following second question:

> If I loan some money without interest (but expecting payment) to my brother, does it constitute a gift?

Those are basically duplicate questions, assuming the second is no more specific than that.  The second should be marked as a dup.  Then, if the OP is specifically asking "Does the fact that it's my brother make a difference?", then the question should be edited (or a new question opened):

> Is a loan without interest to a family member treated differently than a loan without interest to a non-family member?

Of course, the original question may include answers that cover the different kinds of loans, in which case the OP hopefully got their answer and moved on.